# Is there way to add multiple values to 1 ID in access

Tags: ms-access, addition

I have a table that has Act ID, and another table that has Act ID, percentage complete. This can have multiple entries for different days. I need the sum of the percentage added for the Act ID on the first tableZA.108381.080

```
First table
Act ID            Percent        Date         
ZA.108381.110    Total from 2 table
ZA.108381.120
ZA.108476.020

ZA.108381.110      25%        5/25/19
ZA.108381.110      75         6/1/19
ZA.108381.120
ZA.108476.020
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing calculated values in a table has the disadvantage that these entries may become outdated as the other table is updated. It is preferable to query the tables on the fly to always get uptodate results

```
SELECT A.ActID, SUM(B.Percentage) AS SumPercent
FROM
    table1 A
    LEFT JOIN table2 B
        ON A.ActID = B.ActID
GROUP BY A.ActID
ORDER BY A.ActID
```

This query allows you to add additional columns from the first table. If you only need the ActID from table 1, then you can simplify the query, and instead take it from table 2:

```
SELECT ActID, SUM(Percentage) AS SumPercent
FROM table2
GROUP BY ActID
ORDER BY ActID
```

If you have spaces other other special characters in a column or table name, you must escape it with `[]`. E.g. `[Act ID]`.

Do not change the IDs in the table. If you want to have the result displayed as the ID merged with the sum, change the query to

```
SELECT A.ActID & "." & Format(SUM(B.Percentage), "0.000") AS Result
FROM ...
```

See also: [SQL GROUP BY Statement (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This would be generally considering not good practice. Your primary key should be uniquely identifiable for that specific table, and any other data related to that key should be stored in separate columns.

However since an answer is not a place for a lecture, if you want to store multiple values in you Act ID column, I would suggest changing your primary key to something more generic "RowID". Then using vba to insert multiple values into this field.

However changing the primary key late in a databases life may cause alot of issues or be difficult. So good luck